# how do I specify in qmake 4.5's .pro file that i want to ignore a library in msvc8 (2005)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, qt4

I have a linking problem. It can be solved by specify in msvc8 project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore Specific Library: msvcrtd.lib. That library conflicts with libcpmtd.lib. But can't find how to do the same thing in qmake's .pro file that is used to generate the .vcproj file. Grateful for any hint  /LG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write `QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG += /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd` in you .pro file.

Comment: I  have a same issue, and this answer solves it perfectly. Thanks epatel.