# How to make "qmake -project" ignore specified files/directories

Tags: qt4, qmake

How can I specify qmake (v2.01a) to ignore some files/directories when generating a project file?

Solutions to similar problems, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682164/how-do-i-specify-in-qmake-4-5s-pro-file-that-i-want-to-ignore-a-library-in-msv), suggest editing the .pro file. I want that the .pro file is generated respecting my specified ignores, so that I do not have to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean with the second part of your question. However, I will still try to answer the first part:

Simply add a

```
HEADERS -= myClass.h
SOURCES -= myClass.cpp
```

at the end of your project file. This will exclude these files again, even if they were automatically added to the `HEADER += [...]`-part.

Now the second part of your question: Do you mean you auto-generate the project file with some other tool? Then it should be easy to just add these two lines at the end. Or are you looking for some GUI-button to "ignore" some files? Then you are out of luck (well, you could right click on the files and choose "remove" (do not check "remove from disk") and they will be "ignored" - but I don't think this was what you meant?). And BTW: If you are just fearing to manually touch the project file: you will sooner or later need to modify it manually, so better start editing it manually now than trying to get around this step - you cannot run away forever ;)

The [qMake Variable reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) is a good starting point anyway and everyone working with Qt should bookmark that page :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Qmake documentation for making projects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-running.html#project-mode-options), you want to use the options `-nopwd` and then explicitly pass the files/directories you want to create the project out of.

Comment: Typically, the number of files I want to include greatly exceeds the number of files I want to exclude. Typing in the names of all the files to be included will be quit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do this by marking the folder I wanted to exclude as hidden in Windows properties dialog, a workaround but in the end it was easiet for me